# Which is the correct symbol to format logcat error output?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

What is the correct format to use for logcat errors from Android Studio? I have posted many questions on Stack Overflow with logcat error output. I understand that we have to format our code well by clicking the "{}" symbol or Ctrl+k, but how about logcat output? Should we use backticks (`` ` ``) or code block formatting (the {} symbol), or does it depend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question specifically, paste the output, highlight it, and press the "code" symbol in the toolbar (or hit Ctrl+K) to format it as a code block.

More generally, only use `inline code formatting` when you want to include some kind of code (or error output) *within* a sentence or paragraph. Otherwise, use

```
code block formatting, like so.
```

On a tangential but related note:

**Code formatting is *only for code!***

This was [the original revision of your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/269417/1):

> What is the correct format to use for the error **logCat** in `android studio`? I have posted quite many question on `Stack Overflow` and of course with the error `logcat` . I understand that we have to format our code well by clicking the `{}` symbol or `Ctrl+k`but how about the **logCat**? We have to use `"` or `{}` or depends?

"Android Studio," "Stack Overflow," etc. are most definitely not code. So please do not use code formatting for things that are not code.

Comment: Do you have any guidance of the size of those logcat's? When I run into them they are huge with a doubtful S/N ratio. Or is that just me?

Comment: @rene Not my area of expertise, but I suppose it's better to include too much information than too little (considering code blocks scroll).

Comment: @rene logcat is basically a buffed Java console for Android. Generally, you only want to paste the call stack when there's exception, up until "caused by blabla" for the exact cause.